# Alternatives to Tor on Ubuntu

Tags: tor

Does anyone know of a faster UBUNTU software package alternative to the Tor browser and network for maintaining privacy?

I would like to set up a transparent proxy on my Ubuntu operating system to access the internet in a way that prevents my ISP from connecting me to my IP address.

This is a question, I repeat, about whether Tor is the only way to set this up on machines with the UBUNTU operating system.

I want to make sure that I have compatible software.

Comment: ... and in the event that I ever decide to try to become important, I would rather not have to consider the possibility that my every move has been recorded for potential "leaking" against me. 

The "Your [sic] not important" argument has yet another counter, that the people who are important need all the help they can get in making their use of the software part of a larger group of people. 

There is anonymous access, or cyber-crime wouldn't be a thing. Which it is.

Comment: Do people ask questions about gedit on this forum?

Comment: // , @MeerBorg, Do you really have to be important? Does having no anonymous access really mean that I can't take measures? Does having nothing to hide really mean that I have nothing to fear? https://www.aclu.org/blog/national-security/you-may-have-nothing-hide-you-still-have-something-fear

Perhaps I've spent too much time on security.stackexchange.com, but until I see something better than "There is no anon..." and the like, I'm going to maintain basic precautions for my safety.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better yet, instead of perpetrating a Federal offense by sneaking in to an office ( *I*  know you're kidding and *you* know you're kidding but the Secret Service and other Feds have *no* sense of humor at all, as [Steve Jackson](http://www.sjgames.com/SS/) found out), find a library with open WiFi and connect there. Your webwork will be buried in hundreds of other people's webwork, and, at least around here the libraries are getting down right **uppity** about not giving anything to the Feds (like logs) they can avoid (forex, [not retaining logs for more than 30 days](http://web.multco.us/records/branch-libraries)).

The shorter the [log retention](http://torrentfreak.com/how-long-does-your-isp-store-ip-address-logs-120629/), the better your privacy.

Comment: http://www.librarian.net/wp-content/uploads/antipat4.gif

Comment: // , Authoritarians have three modes: 0. Ignore (wha...? None of our employees know what a Linukz is), 1. Rage(To guantanamo bay with the lot of them!), 2. Charm(See, look at all the security benefits we bring. You need us!), and 3. Self-Pity(Boo hoo, we can't do our jobs without breathing down your necks, because who does plain-old shoe-leather detective work anymore??).